# Logical OR only checks the first value [RESOLVED]

Tags: javascript

My code includes the following-

```
 if(!code1.startsWith(("<video" || "<img"))){return ...}
```

The code only checks if code1 doesn't start with "<video". If the "<video" is false and "<img" is true, it executes the return code.
I am still a learner and hoping for help.

Comment: [The docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) says about the parameter: "_All values ... are coerced to strings_". The argument itself is evaluated before calling the method, that's why "video" is always passed.

Comment: You need two tests. `if(!code1.startsWith("<video") &&  code1.startsWith("<img"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is not supposed to behave like that; but you can achieve it this way:

```
if (!(code1.startsWith("<video") || code1.startsWith("<img"))) {
    return ...
}
```

The code above checks that `code` string NEITHER starts with `<video` NOR
`<img`  - so if it starts with either, return ...

Comment: This worked! I am sorry I misunderstood how it worked. I am validating an input field if what I set was edited (node.js).  Thank you.